# Parse String to list of binary tuples

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, tuples, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to parse a string `"A1B2C3D4"` to `[('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)]` in Haskell.

I'm trying to use a `map` like this `map (\[a, b] -> (a :: Char, b :: Int)) x` where `x` is the string.

This is the function signature I need to follow `:: String -> [(Char, Int)]`.

Unfortunately i'm getting type mismatches, can anyone give any hint how to solve this?

I'm in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: use `chunksOf`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf

Comment: thank you @WillemVanOnsem unfortunately I can't import nothing.

Comment: Your simplest path if you are a beginner at haskell is to write out the recursive solution explicitly.  You might ask yourself, for example, what output you would expect if your string were empty.  Then you might ask yourself how you would handle a string that had two characters, followed by a string that might or might not be empty...

Comment: Thank you @MarcTalbot, I already did the recursive solution of this, but I must use a map in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `map` is really meant for applying a single function to every element of something, one-by-one. Splitting the string how you want requires context (knowing the next letter), so `map` isn't the best choice here.

However, you said your solution is required to be in terms of `map`. It can be done, but it's a bit roundabout. I couldn't think of any way to make `map` split the actual string, but it can certainly be used to transform it to the correct type:

```
isDigit :: Char -> Bool
isDigit c = elem c ['0'..'9']

split :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
split str = let chars  = filter (not . isDigit) str
                nums   = filter isDigit str
                zipped = zip chars nums in
              map (\(a, b) -> (a, read [b])) zipped
```

Comment: A couple minor improvements: `if x then True else False` = `x`, and `"0123456789"` = `['0'..'9']`. The pair of `filter`s makes me want `partition`, but with only Prelude functions this is good.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems.

1. The pattern `[a, b]` in `map (\[a, b] -> ...) x` only matches lists of two elements, so the compiler infers that the function `\[a, b] -> ...` has type `[r] -> s` for some `r` and `s`.

   The compiler knows that `map` has the type `(u -> v) -> [u] -> [v]`, so it unifies `u` with `[r]` and `v` with `s` to infer the type `[[r]] -> [s]` for `map (\[a, b] -> ...)`.

   This means `x` must have type `[[r]]`, that is, it must be a list of lists. But you want `x` to be a `String` which is a synonym for `[Char]`. The compiler can't unify `[[r]]` and `[Char]`, so it objects.
2. You're attempting to "cast" `a` to a `Char` and `b` to an `Int` like you would in C, but you can't do that in Haskell. If you want to convert a `Char` like `'1'` into the `Int` `1`, you need a different approach, like `read`, which you can use to convert from a `String` to an `Int`.

Here's some advice. Don't use `map`. Try writing a recursive solution instead.

Start by considering a few cases:

- what does `myParser ""` return?
- what does `myParser "a1"` return?
- what does `myParser [a,b]` return?
- what does `myParser (a:b:cs)` return?

Comment: I already did the recursive solution of this, but I must use a map in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this but it's really not safe as it doesn't handle incorrect string like `"AA11B2C3"`!

```
splitingN :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitingN _ [] = []
splitingN n l
  | n > 0 = take n l : splitingN n (drop n l)
  | otherwise = error "uhhhhhh"

tuplify :: String -> (Char, Int)
tuplify a = (head a, read $ tail a)

stringy :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
stringy s = tuplify <$> splitingN 2 s

> stringy "A1B2C3D4" == [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4)]
```

A much nicer way but still not fully safe would be:

```
stringy :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
stringy [] = []
stringy (a : b : rest) = (a, b) : splitting rest
stringy [a] = error "uhhhhh"
```

Should really check if `a` and `b` from `(a : b : rest)` are indeed `Char` & `Int`. Also this uses recursion and you mentioned using `map` so might not suffice and it's pretty polymorphic in it's types.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to understand that `map` applies the given function over each member of the list. Once you understand that, you will realize that there is no way you can get the conversion you want by applying a function on the existing list.

This leads to realization that once you have a list of "A1", "B2",... then you can take these and convert it using a map function.

I have given the code for function below. The `split'` function is not safe as it can blow up in lot of cases (expected a string which can be perfectly split into 2 chars). I am also using the function `digitToInt`, for which you need to `import Data.Char`. You did say you want no import, in that case you can write your own `digitToInt` function, look into the library code, it is fairly straightforward.

```
import Data.Char

split' :: String -> [String]
split' [] = []
split' (x:y:xs) = (x:[y]) : split' xs

convert :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
convert input = map (\s -> (s!!0 ,  digitToInt(s!!1) )) $ split' input
```